# jq filter objects with specific values and get Id of parent object

Tags: json, filter, jq

Hi I'm playing a bit with jq and have a problem.

This is my data:

```
{
    "auctionInfo": [{
            "tradeId": 229143000306,
            "itemData": {
                "id": 320854114832,
                "rating": 82
            }
        },
        {
            "tradeId": 229143000307,
            "itemData": {
                "id": 320854114833,
                "rating": 84
            }
        },
        {
            "tradeId": 229143000308,
            "itemData": {
                "id": 320854114834,
                "rating": 84
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I now want are alle tradeIds where the rating is 84.

So I tried it with this filter:

```
| jq -r .auctionInfo[].itemData | select(.rating==84)
```

But with this filter I'm inside the itemData and have no access to the tradeId which I'm interested for. I'm not really familiar with jq so might be a basic question but how can I reach the tradeId from where I'm standing with this filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need to do is below. The logic is you need to list all array objects, filter on the rating value to get the subset and print the `tradeId` for those objects

```
jq '.auctionInfo[] | select(.itemData.rating == 84).tradeId'
```